# why is there no easy way to round a float to significant figures in python?

Tags: python, numpy, rounding, figure

Why do we have to write our own functions to round to sig figs?

I.e.

```
round(x, sig-int(floor(log10(abs(x))))-1)
```

II know we can use f-string formatting: `f"{33.44:.2g}"` to get a float as a string, intelligently rounded to sigfigs for display: `"33.0"`.

I tried looking in the standard library. Is there a specific reason we can't get one?

#### Edit

clarified the existing functionality: float-> string conversion.

There are a number of reasons that this is useful:

- many engineering calculatios only require 3-5 sigfigs
- you can use the eqauality operator directly `x==y` rather than `np.isclose(x, y, rtol=1e-5)`.
- if you are using print, sympy, pandas, matplotlib or a library like hand calcs, every single time, you have to print to screen, your only option to control sigfigs is to convert to a string and manually specify the f-string `f"{x:.3g}"`,  rather that just writing the raw float `x`.
- Yes it is obviously true that 'python uses binary defined floating points, not decimal numbers, so it is never really 'to 5 sigificant figures technically' . But if you spend 2 seconds using python you will recognise that the default behaviors is to cut the float off after 15 decimal places. Hence why we have the round() function in the first place.

Default digit display ignores after 16 dp:

```
>>> 1 + 1e-15
1.000000000000001
>>> 1 + 1e-16
1.0
```

Also note that equality operations work when they are equal beyond 15 decimal places:

```
>>> 1== (1 + 1e-15)
False
>>> 1== (1 + 1e-16)
True
```

All I am asking is why we don't have the signfig operation.

Comment: `np.round` specifies decimals, not sig fig.

Comment: Looks like https://pypi.org/project/sigfig/ might be a good option?

Answer (score 2):

Because it's not a useful operation.

Rounding a floating-point value when converting it to a string for output is useful. To use your example:

```py
x = 33.44
print(f"x is approximately {x:.2g}")
```

prints

```
x is approximately 33
```

which is a sensible thing to do.

But rounding a floating-point value to some number of decimal places *and storing the result as a floating-point value* is not useful -- nor is it even possible in general.

Say we have a value of `33.44` and we want to round it to one decimal place, yielding `33.4`. We can do that:

```py
x = 33.44
y = math.floor(x*10) / 10 # or round(y, 1)
```

But the actual value stored in `y` is not `33.4`. It's probably something like `33.39999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375`, because that's the closest approximation we can get in binary 64-bit floating-point. The value `33.4` cannot be stored exactly.

A better approach is to store and compute floating-point values with as much precision as the system provides, and round the result *only* when you're reading to convert to a human-readable string for output.

Comment: Why does the `round` function exist then? How does your argument not apply to that as well?

Comment: And why do you do `math.floor(x*10) / 10` instead of `round(x, 1)`?

Comment: @KellyBundy Using `round()` on floating-point number with a positive `ndigits` is not particularly useful, and what I wrote above applies. But Python also supports decimal real numbers via the [`decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html). Rounding a decimal value to, say, 2 digits after the decimal point is perfectly sensible -- and the built-in `round` function doesn't arbitrarily forbid operations on floating-point values. The [documentation for `round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) addresses this.

Comment: @KellyBundy  didn't use `round(x, 1)` simply because I didn't think of it; actually, I didn't know about the built-in `round` function, and in particular I didn't know it takes an optional `ndigits` argument.

Comment: Well, the question used it, you could've seen it there :-). I'm still not convinced that one kind of rounding is "perfectly sensible" and the other is "not useful". Perhaps the best answer can be found in last year's [feature request](https://discuss.python.org/t/rounding-to-significant-figures-feature-request-for-math-library/16395) with a lengthy discussion including multiple core devs. But I don't care enough to read that much...

Comment: @KellyBundy Rounding the decimal value `33.44` gives you a decimal result of exactly `33.4`. Rounding the floating-point value `33.44` (which is stored as `33.4399999999999999987509990972966988920234143733978271484375`) gives you `33.400000000000000001387778780781445675529539585113525390625`. How is the latter useful? Why would you want to store that incorrectly rounded result in a floating-point variable rather than keeping it in full precision and rounding on output, when converting to a string?

Comment: *"How is the latter useful?"* I don't know. But the functionality does exist. Just not by asking for a number of *significant* digits. So apparently someone did find it useful enough to put it into Python.

Comment: 2 reasons:  1). Equality operations work when they are equal beyond 15 decimal places. Use the equality operator directly `x==y` rather than `np.isclose(x, y, rtol=1e-5)`. e.g :
`>>> 1== (1 + 1e-15); False` and `>>> 1== (1 + 1e-16);True`.
2.)  Default display ignores zeroes beyond 16 decimal places. Easier to write raw float or table as  `x` or `df` rather than `f"{x:.3g}"` or `df.style.format({'column': '{:.3g}'})` if using matplotlib, pandas, plotly, or anything else. e.g. ::`>>> 1 + 1e-15;1.000000000000001` and `>>> 1 + 1e-16;1.0`.
```